# Android: No resource found that matches the given name... selectableItemBackgroundBorderless

Tags: android

My Android project gave me several errors like this one:
**Description**: 
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless'). 
**Project**
(Akva20150407)
**Path**
C:\Users\bls\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\22.0.0\embedded.\res\layout\mr_media_route_controller_material_dialog_b.xml(0,0)

How do you resolve these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack tracer or error message will tell you this is linked to the package Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.
Removing this package from your project will resolve all related errors like these.

Comment: What if someone want to use MediaRouter library from Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter and have this error, I don't think its solution.